# At what rate are new addresses appearing in the blockchain?

Tags: transactions, address, volume

How many new addresses are the recipient of transactions hourly? daily? weekly? monthly?

I understand that this is always changing, so bonus points if you can provide code to calculate it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Blockchain has a chart of new addresses per day:

http://blockchain.info/charts/n-unique-addresses